# How can I extract the file names used by IEFrame.dll?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am working with a program that uses the IEframe.dll to display HTML files which are stored on my disk. I have access to these files, but I need to know in what order they are accessed.

Is there any way to communicate with the rendering engine to extract the files in use at the moment?

I guess another way to skin this cat will be to write a script to extract the list of files in use by a process.

Note: I already tried **"handle.exe -p programname > filenames.txt"** but I can not see the files there. The program has the option to open these files in a HTML editor and this is how I can know what files are used but this is slow, I need something that I can script it

Edit: I guess the correct name for the rendering engine is "The web browser control" I am not a programmer and I am not sure if I am using the right terminology

Edit2: OK After some googling I found this:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html

This program seems to do part of the job in the sense that it able to show me some info but I still don't see a file names there, just handles which I presume are temporary

Edit3: after some reading I realized that the component used by my app is IEFrame.dll and it also uses MSHTML.dll (this seems to be control to display HTML files. The app displays two web paged on the same screen, both files are on my HDD. I am not sure which component is accessing the files on my HDD.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is how I could find the info that I needed: I used SysInternals' Process Monito with the following filters:
ProcessName=Systmem
Path: Path to the folder where my files were

You will get records for the file access and if you filter what you need (in my case I used Detail contains SyncType) there you go you have your log for your app.
Use Ctrl+C to copy the log and dump it into Excel or whatever to further process it

Another way to do it is via Event Viewer and Windows Audit policies. Audit the access to that folder and export the Event log. The output has a lot more info that you do not really need